# Disable generate static web assets task in blazor web assembly

Tags: blazor-webassembly, multi-project

I added this to my project file:

```
<StaticWebAssetsEnabled>false</StaticWebAssetsEnabled>
```

But I get this error:

```
  Error MSB4036 The "DefineStaticWebAssets" task was not found. Check the following: 1.)
 The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The 
task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The
 task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files 
located in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current
\Bin\amd64" directory.  Client1 C:\Users\..\.nuget\packages
\microsoft.net.sdk.webassembly.pack\8.0.0\build
\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WebAssembly.Browser.targets  280
```

So how to disable generate static web assets task completely?